# How do I change the default strings in Wordpress backend?

Tags: string, wordpress, admin, backend

I'm developing my own theme (and plugins) and wants to be able to change the default strings on the admin screen. To be concrete, I want to change the description of the excerpt-field on the admin edit screen, which by default reads:

```
Excerpts are optional hand-crafted summaries of your content that can be used in your theme. Learn more about manual excerpts (link to WP Codex).
```

I'm not looking for a way to translate it into another language, but just a way to change the string.

Which file contains this information? I'm guessing no hooks or filters support this? I've been looking through the wp-include folder, without luck.

Comment: grep "Excerpts are optional hand-crafted summaries of your content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `grep` as suggested in the comments by paislee, I found it. It turned out to be located here:

`/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php`